# Compare deeply nested data structures ignoring array order

Tags: arrays, perl, compare

I need to compare deeply nested data structures using perl.
The structures can contain scalars, arrays and hashes.
I would prefer a XS implementation.
The data originally arrives as JSON.

In the data schema the item order inside arrays is not guaranteed and makes it hard to compare.

I tried with Test::Deep. The Approach is easy when the only array is at top level, but is heavy when the order-insensitive array is nested deeper in the structure.

Comment: What type of comparison do you have in mind? To check whether the data structures are identical? All array elements are equal, and all hash keys matches?

Comment: yes, comparing if all items/hashes have the same key/values. All arrays containing the same elements order-insensitive. 
the method gets 2 references(much like Test::Deep) and figures out the type, nesting and topology itself. The differences should be available a return or at least logged.

Comment: Can the arrays contain other things than scalars? I.e. sub arrays or hashes? If so, how can you determine the correct order? E.g. which array ref should be compared to which array ref?

Answer (score 2):

If the arrays only can contain scalars. You could try use [`Data::Compare`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Data::Compare). Here is an example with numerical arrays. You need to write a plugin for `Data::compare`, see [`Data::Compare::Plugins`](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/Data-Compare/lib/Data/Compare/Plugins.pod) for more information.

**test.pl**:

```
use lib '.';
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Compare;

my $h1 = { a => {b => [2, 1, 3] }, c => 3};
my $h2 = { a => {b => [1, 2, 3] }, c => 3};

print 'The structures $h1 and $h2 are ',
  Compare($h1, $h2) ? "" : "not ", "identical.\n";
```

**./Data/Compare/Plugins/ArrayBag.pm**:

```
package Data::Compare::Plugins::ArrayBag;

use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Compare;

sub _register {
    return [
        ['ARRAY', 'ARRAY', \&array_compare],
    ];
}

sub array_compare {
    my($a1, $a2) = @_;

    return 0 if (scalar @$a1) != (scalar @$a2);
    my @ar1 = sort { $a <=> $b } @$a1;
    my @ar2 = sort { $a <=> $b } @$a2;
    for my $i (0..$#ar1 ) {
        return 0 if $ar1[$i] != $ar2[$i];
    }
    return 1;
}

_register();
```

**Output** from running `test.pl`:

```
The structures $h1 and $h2 are identical.
```

Comment: Note that the `sort` may need to be changed to use `cmp` instead of `<=>` if the data is string and not numeric.

Comment: How would I go about adding the same logic for arrays that contain hashes as well?

Answer (score -1):

Procedure calculates md5_hex for string of sorted md5_hex of sub-structures (recursively).
Check arrays @a1 and @a2 - they have hashes, hashes have 'undef' and both arrays and hashes have different order. But from data perspective - they are identical.

Hope this sample will work for you better then some modules.

```
use strict;
use Digest::MD5 qw(md5_hex);

my @a1 = ({a => 1, b => 1,  d1 => ['aa', 'cc'], d => undef, c => 1}, 2, 10, {b => 2, a => 2}, 3, 8);
my @a2 = (2, 3, {a => 2, b => 2}, 8, 10, {c => 1, a => 1, b => 1, d => undef, d1 => ['cc', 'aa']});

my $refSum1 = &referenceSum(\@a1);
my $refSum2 = &referenceSum(\@a2);

if ($refSum1 eq $refSum2)
{
  print 'Objects are identical!' . "\n";
}
else
{
  print 'Objects are DIFFERENT!' . "\n";
}

##################################################################
sub referenceSum
{
  my $oRef = shift;
  my $refType = ref($oRef);
  my @sumArr = ();
  if ($refType eq 'SCALAR')
  {
    push(@sumArr, md5_hex($$oRef));
  }
  elsif ($refType eq 'ARRAY')
  {
    foreach my $k (@{$oRef})
    {
      if (ref($k) =~ /(SCALAR|ARRAY|HASH)/i)
      {
        push(@sumArr, &referenceSum($k));
      }
      else
      {
        push(@sumArr, &referenceSum(\$k));
      }
    }
  }
  elsif ($refType eq 'HASH')
  {
    foreach my $k (keys(%{$oRef}))
    {
      my $val = %{$oRef}{$k};
      if (ref($val) =~ /(SCALAR|ARRAY|HASH)/i)
      {
        push(@sumArr, md5_hex(scalar($k)) . '-' . &referenceSum($val));
      }
      else
      {
        push(@sumArr, md5_hex(scalar($k)) . '-' . &referenceSum(\$val));
      }
    }
  }
  return md5_hex(join('|', (sort {$a cmp $b} @sumArr)));
}
##################################################################
```

Comment: It looks like you could do this with the actual values and ignore the md5 part completely. Imagine having to do thousands of md calls to figure this out. Instead, you want to fail as quickly as you can.

Comment: I have example of 2 arrays in code. Try to compare them and receive "identical" with any other solution. Then I'd be glad to see that solution. Regarding amount of calls - goal is not a performance, but make sure structures are identical from data content.

Comment: But when do you think MD5 is going to do for you if you are making two big strings to compare? For other code, you can look at modules such as Test::Deep and Data::Compare.

Comment: Once again - there are 2 arrays, containing anonymous hashes in different positions, and I'd be glad to see any other code that will tell 'yes, those are equal'. Why you telling me how bad or useless my code is, instead of providing other working example? Especially if you know where to look?

Comment: Seems you focused on word 'array' and totally do not understand what my code is doing. I'm not writing books, I'm writing algorithms. If position in array should be ignored, then elements needs to be sorted. But hashes, as array elements, can not be sorted, so I'm calculating checksum/signature for objects and sort those, then getting final crc/sign. This allows me to have any kind of structure inside and return only signature. This also can be useful when comparing 1000 objects to find identical. And in case when objects are not available at the same time (async data).

Comment: I understand that you have to traverse the entire structure before you even check for a difference, and even then you wouldn't know what the difference was.